# yoast seo выводит meta теги не в head

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины, yoast

плагин выводит meta теги не head, а в body именно в "мясе" сайта, подскажите как решить эту проблему[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это означает, что wp_head() вызывается в body, а не в head.